# How to remove the seasonality of a time series

Tags: r, time-series, multiple-seasonalities

I have got hourly data, which may have daily and annually seasonality. The ACF plot of the data are shown as follows, which is plotted up to 44 lags (upper left), 100 lags (upper right), and plot of `diff(data, 24)` (bottom left), and `diff(data,24*365)` (bottom right). I also tried to take the difference of 24, and then 24*365, but still does not work.

I am wondering that how to remove the seasonality in this time series. Thanks.

[image]